# How to code the form submission for a joomla component in an efficient way?

Tags: component

I'm new to Joomla and I'm developing a component which includes the creation and submission of  a form. The form submission example at http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Example_of_a_frontend_update_function is very useful, but the warning on top of the page suggesting the example does "not adhere to best practices and do not make optimal use of the flexibility provided by Joomla." and "This code is not harmful and can be used in components, but could be written in a simpler and more maintainable way" is suggesting there is a better and simpler way.

Any suggestions? I hope my question is not too general but as a Joomla starter I just try to apply the best practises from the start...

Appreciate your help

Comment: Generate a component which **looks similar** to yours here:
http://www.component-creator.com/en/

Then take a look at the source code ;) You can also look at existing components such as com_user

Comment: thnx for the suggestions; had a look at the com_user code; very useful

Answer (score 1):

Best idea is to use core components for that. Use com_content (my favorite frontend is at `components/com_content` and backend is at `administrator/com_content`) for the "best practices". For the database tables you can refer to its tables as well (its in `PREFIX_content`).

This is the best way to learn as currently a lot of the documentation is outdated, so you may end up using depreciated methods and such (most do tell you). It does take time but it is well worth it, Joomla has a good structure and once you get the hang of looking at the core for references you can find what you need fairly fast.